# Selecting records from a table and then selecting a count of records from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables that looks like this;

```
   Table: pictures
  `picture_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `picture_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `picture_description` text NOT NULL,
  `picture_src` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `picture_filetype` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `picture_width` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `picture_height` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `upload_date` datetime NOT NULL,
```

--

```
   Table: picture_votes
  `vote_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `picture_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vote` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
```

And what I want to do is to select every field from `pictures` table and then a count of all the records in `picture_votes` where `pictures.picture_id = picture_votes.picture_id`, like for example;

```
picture_id => 1
picture_title => 'Pic title'
picture_description => 'Pic description'
picture_src => 'b8b3f2c3a85f1a46fbf2ee132d81f783'
picture_filetype => 'jpg'
picture_width => 612
picture_height => 612
user_id => 1
upload_date => '2013-10-12 12:00:00'
vote_count => 3 // Amount of records in `picture_votes` that has `picture_id` = 1
```

I've come up with (where `$limit` is the amount of pictures to select);

```
SELECT pictures.*, count(picture_votes.vote) as vote_count
    FROM pictures, picture_votes
    WHERE pictures.picture_id = picture_votes.picture_id
    ORDER BY upload_date DESC
    LIMIT $limit
```

This selects only 1 picture and a count of *all* records in `picture_votes`.

Comment: Add `GROUP BY pictures.picture_id`. An a side note, I prefer my `JOIN` clauses in the `ON`, not in the `WHERE`.

Comment: `SELECT pictures.*, count(picture_votes.vote) as vote_count
                                    FROM pictures JOIN picture_votes ON (pictures.picture_id = picture_votes.picture_id)
                                    GROUP BY pictures.picture_id
                                    ORDER BY pictures.upload_date DESC
                                    LIMIT $limit`
works but it will only select pictures that has a vote in the `picture_votes` table. Pictures without votes are not selected.

Comment: Ah, so you want a `LEFT JOIN` (which will give you all pictures, even without votes).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm now. Is there any way to change the `vote_count` column to 0 if it's `null`, or do I have to do that in PHP?

Comment: `IFNULL(COUNT(...),0)`

Comment: Sweet! I have so much to learn about SQL-queries. Self-learning is so easy with Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **really** want to use **LEFT** join, because that will return all the pictures, not just the ones with a vote.  You also should do sum(pv.vote) vs COUNT() incase your votes ever are more than 1 (hey, it can happen! Just think: Premium account == x2 votes ;-)

```
SELECT p.*, SUM(pv.vote) votes FROM pictures p
LEFT JOIN picture_votes pv
    ON pv.picture_id=p.picture_id
GROUP BY pv.picture_id
```

If you ever wanted to sort by, say, top 10 vote count:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT p.*, SUM(pv.vote) votes FROM pictures p
    LEFT JOIN picture_votes pv
        ON pv.picture_id=p.picture_id
    GROUP BY pv.picture_id
) AS aggregate
ORDER BY votes DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: The way I've done it now is that a vote (`pv.vote`) is either +1 or -1. Do you have another solution as how to count votes that are just increments by 1 or decrements by 1? What I want do to is count the total amount of votes, not the sum, by the way. Thanks for the answer, works like a charm.

Comment: to count the total number, no matter what their value, use COUNT(pv.vote) AS totalVotes

Answer (score 1):

If `picture_id` is indexed on your `picture_votes` table, then the following may be even faster than a join:

```
SELECT  *
      , ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM picture_votes WHERE picture_id = pictures.picture_id )
FROM    pictures
```

This may skip the contents of the table entirely and allow you to simply count the records in the hash table, which should be faster.

Comment: How versatile is this query? Would I for example be able to sort by top 10 vote count like @Theodore R. Smith's solution can? How much faster is this if the pictures table has 10,000 records and vote table has 100,000 records?

Comment: @WillB - as with all performance tuning, to a large extent you'd just need to try it out.